# Python/Pandas: How to find rows that are duplicated in two df columns?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a df where I want to check for duplicate rows in only two of the columns, but if those columns are similar to the previous row, then I'd like to isolate/print them. So for example, if rows 12 - 89 have the same value in column 2 and column 3 as the previous row(s), then I want to know this range of rows.

See image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iv3N.png) for example of df where 'pm10_ugm3' and 'pm25_ugm3' are duplicated but other columns are not:

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try [the dataframe's duplicated function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).  This returns an index that you can use to slice/select those rows.  Some variation of this will get you close:

```
dup_rows = df.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep='first')
print(df[dup_rows])
```